# How to call this get api with sending the body using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I can call the the api in the postman like this.

The data return fine in the postman

[image]

But when I try to get the api from the axios request
the api always give me 500

What am I doing wrong?

```
axios
    .get('/dwapi/productsapi/GetProductList', {
      params: {
        group: 'Baby&Kids',
        subgroup: '',
        subsubgroup: '',
        pagesize: '',
        pagenum: '4',
        minprice: '',
        maxprice: '',
        brand: '',
        size: '',
        promotion: '',
        bhgexclusive: '',
        sortorder: '',
        sortby: '',
        search: '',
      },
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      // dispatch({
      //    type: FETCH_PRODUCT_LIST,
      //    payload: res.data,
      // });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios
    .get('/dwapi/productsapi/GetProductList', {
        group: 'Baby&Kids',
        subgroup: '',
        subsubgroup: '',
        pagesize: '',
        pagenum: '4',
        minprice: '',
        maxprice: '',
        brand: '',
        size: '',
        promotion: '',
        bhgexclusive: '',
        sortorder: '',
        sortby: '',
        search: '',
      }
    )
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      // dispatch({
      //    type: FETCH_PRODUCT_LIST,
      //    payload: res.data,
      // });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to send your parameters in the body and not the URL parameters, thus you should not be specifying the `params` property:

```
axios
    .get('/dwapi/productsapi/GetProductList', {
      group: 'Baby&Kids',
      subgroup: '',
      subsubgroup: '',
      pagesize: '',
      pagenum: '4',
      minprice: '',
      maxprice: '',
      brand: '',
      size: '',
      promotion: '',
      bhgexclusive: '',
      sortorder: '',
      sortby: '',
      search: '',
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      // dispatch({
      //    type: FETCH_PRODUCT_LIST,
      //    payload: res.data,
      // });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
```

Comment: still getting status 500. IDK why

Answer (score 0):

In axios, you can try with `data` instead of `params`. And let me know what will be the result.

```
axios
    .get('/dwapi/productsapi/GetProductList', {
      data: {
        group: 'Baby&Kids',
        subgroup: '',
        subsubgroup: '',
        pagesize: '',
        pagenum: '4',
        minprice: '',
        maxprice: '',
        brand: '',
        size: '',
        promotion: '',
        bhgexclusive: '',
        sortorder: '',
        sortby: '',
        search: '',
      },
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      // dispatch({
      //    type: FETCH_PRODUCT_LIST,
      //    payload: res.data,
      // });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
```

Comment: I get `[Error: Network Error]` When I try to change params to data

Comment: Can you attach the browser's network tab screenshot?